# Problems about variable variable $_POST in PHP in form

Tags: php, forms

I would like to execute this code but an error is displayed :

**Notice: Undefined index: choix in D:\xampp\htdocs\formulaire\cible.php on line 1** of cible.php (`<?php echo $_POST['choix']; ?>`)

*Code of formulaire.php (in htlm)*

```
<select name="choix">
    <option value="choix1">Choix 1</option>
    <option value="choix2">Choix 2</option>
    <option value="choix3">Choix 3</option>
    <option value="choix4">Choix 4</option>
</select>
```

Code for cible.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['choix']; ?>
```

Thank you

completed form

```
<form action="cible.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="nom" />
        <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
    </p>
</form>


<select name="choix">
    <option value="choix1">Choix 1</option>
    <option value="choix2">Choix 2</option>
    <option value="choix3">Choix 3</option>
    <option value="choix4">Choix 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: where is the full html form?

Comment: Yes, we would like to see your `action` and `method` attributes.

Comment: :) move the `select` inside the `form`.

Comment: ok i I changed the post sorry

Comment: Thank you @IncredibleHat, It's working